# C: 'unlink' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I am writing the code for Inter process communication.

In the receiver process code i have called the method

```
unlink("datapipe");
```

I have included the #include  header file also.

finally i got the following error :

```
receiver.c:12: error: 'unlink' was not declared in this scope
```

Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: *What* header file have you included?

Comment: You probably forgot `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: See the [official `unlink` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) for which file to include. Or just do a simple `man 2 unlink`.

Answer (score 10):

As per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html), `unlink` can be found in the `unistd.h` header file:

```
SYNOPSIS:
    #include <unistd.h>
    int unlink(const char *path);
```

The `sys/stat.h` header only defines such things as are required for using the return result of `fstat()`, `lstat()` and `stat()`.